# What are the arclengths of the curves described by the intersection of two cylinders (different sizes): A) tangential cylinders B) angled cylinders

Tags: integration, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm assuming a numerical integration is required to determine the arclengths, and if someone knows the integrals that describes the arclength, that would be appreciated.

With the help of stack exchange, I was able to calculate a similar problem: the arclength of a curve of two orthogonal intersecting cylinders (a steinmetz curve) by using the trapezoidal method for integration:  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36913/calculate-the-arc-length-of-a-steinmetz-curve-numerically/36914?noredirect=1#comment72347_36914

Here are two pictures describing the two cases I'm interested in:

[Angled Cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RYj5.png)
[Tangential cylinders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUGFp.png)